# Image element moving on different responsive screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my website responsive and I have been 99% successful. There is just one thing that I cannot seem to fix. In the following screenshot I am showing the page that seems to be broken. It is set to Ipad view. You will notice the top image is shifted right. I will post as much code as I think is relevant below.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="home-box home-box-one">

        {% for photograph in photos %} 

            <div class="photo-box">
                <a href="{% url 'viewphoto' photograph.slug %}"><img id="recent-photo" src="{{photograph.photo.url}}" style="object-fit: cover;"></a>
                
            </div>
 
        {% endfor %}     
        
    <div class="home-btn-container">
        <a href="{% url 'gallery' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 home-button custom-button">View Gallery</button></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
img#recent-photo {
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.home-btn-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.photo-box {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-image: url(/static/images/background.jpg);
  margin-bottom: 5rem !important;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Can you see with inspector tools or there isn't an invisible element there? I replicated this in JSFiddle and it seems to work just right.

Comment: Did you select yo view with iPad Air? I have inspected it yes but I can't seem to see anything

Comment: I've just checked on another iPad with fresh cache and it's doing the same as the original question describes. This is baffling me

Comment: I don't think the issue is with your styling. If I reproduce this with multiple images in the home-box div I don't have this issue. ( I used ipad Air and mini view in chrome )

Comment: Hmmm, I cannot work this out

Comment: Do you have the same situation if you do it without php? I believe that is what you are using. Just add a couple hard coded images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the link for your site I found the problem:

[image: empty a tag]

There is an empty A tag rendered in the html file. If you remove this the pictures will be centered